# When I add binary numbers, i can't actually input one without an error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print ("Input Binary Number")

num1 = bin(input())

print( "Now another one")

num2 = bin(input())

answer = ( num1 + num1)

print ("adding them together will give you" , answer)

input ("press enter to finish")
```

I'm not able to input binary numbers

Comment: Can you clarify what's wrong here? Is it throwing an error? Giving the wrong output?

Comment: Hint: what type of data does `input()` return? What type of data does `bin` accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's at the most basic input, and work up to the final result.

First, `input()` returns a string, so `1011101` will be `"1011101"`.

Now we want to store the string as an int, so we use `int(input())`.

Unfortunately, this reads the string in base 10, and we want to read in base 2, so we use `int(input(), 2)`.

We don't use the bin() function let, because this function converts the int back to a string, and the "+" operation does concatenation, not addition.

Now the value is stored correctly as an int, so we can do the addition normally: `answer = num1 + num2`

Once we have the sum stored, we want to save the result to a binary string. To do this we write `answerString = bin(answer)` or `answerString = bin(answer)[2:]` if we want to remove the leading "0b" that bin appends.

Now we can print answerString to display the result.

A demo that I wrote:

```
num1 = int(input(), 2)
num2 = int(input(), 2)
answer = num1 + num2
answerString = bin(answer)[2:]
print(answerString)
```

input:

```
1001001
1010100
```

output:

```
10011101
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to first convert the input to an int then to bin

```
num1 = bin(int(input()))
```

also you probably meant:

```
answer = (num1 + num2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`bin` converts an integer to a string giving a binary representation of the number.  What you need to do is take your input as a string and convert it using `int`.  `int` takes a second parameter that is the base - in this case 2.

Something like `num1 = int(input(), 2)` should do the trick.

Comment: In Python 3, `raw_input()` was renamed `input()`, and the original `input()` removed.

Comment: @chepner - I should have remembered that (and looked at the tags properly!)